# Hi i'm having problem in removing input tag after adding. Problem is When I click on remove button Input tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

```js
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;
        
        $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                        alert(i);
                    
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label><span> <button id="remScnt">Remove</button><span></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });
        
        $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
                    alert(i);
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parent('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fragment_1223">
    <button id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</button>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Hi i'm having problem in removing input tag after adding. Problem is When I click on remove button Input tag

check the code in editor

Comment: "check the code in editor" - how can we? Please may you add a [mcve] by editing the question?

Comment: use event delegation model for dynamic added element as `jQuery(document)...`

Comment: First of you are getting multiple elements with the same ID and that is a no go. ID should always be unique. Also the buttons will not work becuase they are not in the dom when this part runs `$('#remScnt')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Event delegation model for dynamic element,

replace `$('#remScnt').on('click', function() {`  with `jQuery(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function() {` and use `parents` instead of `parent`

```js
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;
        
        $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                        alert(i);
                    
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label><span> <button id="remScnt">Remove</button><span></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });
        
         jQuery(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
                    alert(i);
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fragment_1223">
    <button id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</button>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this will still result in duplicated `id` and that is a no no

Comment: There is small issue while removing Input tag. I want to remove input tag which I clicked, but in your solution The last input tag is getting removed every time .

Comment: add input by filling values like 1,2,3 and remove one, check which is got removed.

Comment: alert id is not the one which going to remove as per your code.

Comment: @MandapatiGanesh and Devsi, Using duplicated IDs can make problems. Please use class instead

Comment: yes correct @CarstenLøvboAndersen, better to use class instead of id.